# Spring Hibernate problems

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a problem. I want to add option, where admin user can delete users accounts and can not delete admin accounts, but I can't do this. I tried to do it like this

```
@RequestMapping("/adminRemoveUser/{id}")
    public String removeUser(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        if(this.userService.getUserById(id).getUserRole().contains("ROLE_ADMIN")){
            return "errorDeleteUser";
        }
        else{
            this.userService.removeUser(id);
            if(this.userService.getPage(pageNumber).size()==0)
                pageNumber--;
            return "redirect:/adminuserspage="+pageNumber;
        }
}
```

but it doesn't works. Please help ;)

Here's [link](https://github.com/dominik04u/SpringHibernate.git) to the repo.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: change `contains` to `equals`...might help

Comment: I used equals too. It's the same problem. Aplication throw exception NestedServletException

It return Set

Comment: so where does ur problem lie exactly?

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: pl.Dominik.spring.model.User.userRole, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: @DominikAdamski Add the stacktrace to your question please.

Comment: @Jens but how can i do it?

Comment: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: pl.Dominik.spring.model.User.userRole, could not initialize proxy - no Session
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)

Comment: @DominikAdamski Use the edit function

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you search on that error you will find plenty of articles on the cause and possible solutions so I am not going to bother explaining it.

The quickest fix but not necessarily the best is to mark the @OneToMany from User to Role as EAGER.

An alternative would be to delegate the check to your Service layer and throw an Exception from here.

```
@RequestMapping("/adminRemoveUser/{id}")
public String removeUser(@PathVariable("id") int id){

    try{
        userService.removeUser(id);

        if(userService.getPage(pageNumber).size() == 0){
            pageNumber--;
        }

        return "redirect:/adminuserspage="+pageNumber;
    }
    catch(SomeException ex){
        return "errorDeleteUser";
    }

}
```

Other solutions are available.

Comment: IllegalOperationException cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: You either create it or use use some existing Exception type which may be suitable. UnsupportedOperationException? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Exception.html

Comment: It doesn't work like I want. Ok. It's nit necessary. Thank You for help ;)